# Risk associated with not obfuscating code of hybrid mobile apps which are built using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am looking for guidance on risk associated with not obfuscating code of hybrid mobile apps which are built using PhoneGap.

- What is the risk if code contains sensitive data like twitter or Facebook  keys? How this information can be exploited?
- Does the obfuscation eliminates the risk of losing the sensitive data?
- What are the tools available for obfuscation and what level of testing is required once the code is obfuscated?
- Are there any limitations of obfuscation?
- Are there any known issues related with obfuscation which needs to be fixed before/after the obfuscation?

Comment: Since the code needs to be parsed by the WebView, that means anyone could get your HTMl/JavaScript and decode it to get at your sensitive data. I don't think it'd be super difficult to unzip an .apk and pull out the HTML resources. I don't think it would happen very much in practice. I'm sure there are lots of resources out there that talk about different security and privacy policies of the various mobile OS's. All I know for sure is that storing private keys in HTML/JavaScript is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) for obfuscate any type of android app

also you can easily find sourceforge examples [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html)